# Monitor log continuously in Linux and send email whenever error is found?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I was trying to monitor a trading log in Linux and whenever there's any 'ERROR' detected, it should send an email to me and this monitoring process should keep going forever. My current solution is as following:

```
tail -f trade.log | grep -iE 'error' | mail -s 'Error Detected' XXX@XXX.com
```

But it seems that this is not working. As it may send an email, but the email body is empty and only one email is sent. What should I do? And any other nice solutions are welcomed. Thank you!!

Comment: You can try to add a `--line-buffered` option to `grep` to ensure it flushes the buffer immediately for each incoming line from `tail`.